# How do you create MS Graph open extensions with the same id on multiple users?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to add some profile data onto users in my AAD tenant. Using Microsoft Graph, I can add a an open extension to one user.

```
URL (POST): https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/extensions

Body: {
    "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Graph.OpenTypeExtension",
    "extensionName": "mydev.profile",
    "value1": "1000",
    "value2": "3"
}
```

This works, and I can update it with

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/extensions/mydev.profile
```

However, if I try to add the same extension to a different user, I get an error that says the id is already used.

```
Request (POST): https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{object-id}/extensions

Body: {
    "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Graph.OpenTypeExtension",
    "extensionName": "mydev.profile",
    "value1": "1000",
    "value2": "3"
}

Response (409 Conflict): {
  "error": {
    "code": "Request_BadRequest",
    "message": "An extension already exists with given id.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "27c9c777-d4ce-4466-adce-a18505fffb30",
      "date": "2017-05-23T14:43:17"
    }
  }
}
```

The [documentation I'm reading](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/opentypeextension_post_opentypeextension) doesn't say anything about the id having to be unique in any scope. Am I missing something?

(I've tried doing this through Microsoft Graph Explorer, and through Postman. Same result.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. We'll be investigating this bug. We have a couple of things going on here. I don't think specifying the `@odata.type` in the request is required, but when you add it we set the `id` the same as the supplied `extensionName`. Secondly we also scope the `id` to be unique per tenant (at least for directory resources like `user`), which is wrong.  I imagine that it makes more sense for this to be unique **per object**, especially if you are looking to filter on all users that have your extension's (common) id.

If you are looking to create multiple open extensions with the same `extensionName`, that is possible without specifying the `@odata.type` in the payload.  When you do that we generate a unique `id`.  Or you could specify a different open property to tag the extension name. The downside is that until we make a fix, you won't be able to perform the aforementioned filter.

I'll respond when we make some fixes to this.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I agree the id should be unique per object. Otherwise, it loses a lot of its usefulness. The example I saw frequently, creating roaming profiles, simply doesn't work if each user's extension has to have a unique id.

I think I'll try generating a unique extension name based on the user's AD object id. I won't be able to filter, but I'll at least be able to lookup the extension. That fits my use case right now.

I'll be very interested to know when this is fixed, though. Thanks again!

Comment: Any update on the bug?