# What Microsoft Graph User property can I use for additional per user information

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

We're using Azure AD for Authentication on a new Azure app. I have a requirement to add a few supplemental pieces of information to the user information.

Normally, I'd like to use an Open Type Extension on each user, something like this:

```
{
  "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.openTypeExtension",
  "extensionName": "org.test.example",
  "Region": "HQ",
  "Companies": ["1022", "1023", "1145"],
}
```

But, according to  [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44138214/how-do-you-create-ms-graph-open-extensions-with-the-same-id-on-multiple-users), adding open type extensions for multiple users is broken and can't currently be used this way.

I tried to use the **Responsibilities** property, but found out today that I can't use it without a SharePoint license associated with our Azure instance.

So my question is, which User property can I use for this without adding extra licenses? I'm not opposed to putting all the values in one array (that's what we planned to do with Responsibilities), but I'd really like to avoid having to make a round trip to a database to pull this information when each user logs in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue mentioned in [How do you create MS Graph open extensions with the same id on multiple users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44138214/how-do-you-create-ms-graph-open-extensions-with-the-same-id-on-multiple-users) is fixed and in the process of being deployed. I will update once it is available (mostly mid next week).

Comment: The issue is fixed. Please try and let us know if you see any issues.